# how to create a simple collaborative filter with neo4j and cypher or gremlin

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gremlin

So I would like to recommend posts to a user based on a simple collaborative filter.  The filter should work as follows

1. Find the top n users who are most similar to me in the posts that I like (my mentor group)
2. Find the most popular posts amongst this mentor group that I have not already liked

So I have the first part, this would give me my mentors

```
START me=node:node_auto_index(uname = "mike")
MATCH me-[:LIKES]->posts<-[:LIKES]-mentors
RETURN person.uname, count(posts)
ORDER BY count(posts) DESC LIMIT 20;
```

And for the second part, amongst these mentors find the most liked posts that I have not already liked.

How would I run this second part in cypher, or perhaps gremlin if its more efficient.  Would it be a 2 part query where I have to feed one query results into another, or can I combine it all into one query?

Comment: I guess you mean `mentors.uname`

Answer (score 3):

I think this might do what you want:

```
p = [] as Set
g.V('uname','mike').out('likes').aggregate(p).in('likes').groupCount.cap.transform{it.sort{-it.value}[0..19].keySet()}.scatter.out('likes').except(p).groupCount.cap.sort{-it.value}[0..4]
```

where

```
g.V('uname','mike').out('likes').aggregate(p).in('likes').groupCount
```

gives you the mentor group in a hash map with the values being their weight. Next, we take the top 20 of those (having to sort them through a transform) and then find all the posts that those people like except the posts that you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a very similar example at http://console.neo4j.org/r/meljiv, taken from http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-cookbook-similar-favorites.html .

```
START me=node:node_auto_index(name = "Joe")
MATCH me-[:favorite]->stuff<-[:favorite]-person
WHERE NOT(me-[:friend]-person)
RETURN person.name, count(stuff)
ORDER BY count(stuff) DESC
```

Comment: we're actually trying to get the favorites and not the people, so this example you've listed lets us get the first part, the mentor group, but doesn't do the second part of getting recommended favorite posts.

Comment: add one more relation to the MATCH phase: START me=node:node_auto_index(name = "Joe")
MATCH me-[:favorite]->stuff<-[:favorite]-person-[:favorite]-post
WHERE NOT(me-[:favorite]-post)
RETURN post, count(*) as cnt
ORDER BY cnt DESC